# Generating same set of random DenseVector from Apache dictributions - Breeze

Tags: scala, scala-breeze

I am trying to generate a repeatable random DenseVector for a number of distributions. For the native Breeze distributions (Gaussian, Uniform), this is what I am doing:

```
implicit val randBasis = RandBasis.withSeed(2022)
// For uniform
val uniformRandoms = Uniform(20, 40).samplesVector(100)
// For Gaussian:
val normalRandoms = Gaussian(20, 2).samplesVector(100)
```

But, I am struggling to do the same with Triangular distribution, which is using the Apache distribution behind the scenes. The following line generates a different DenseVector everytime:

```
val traingularRandoms = new TriangularDistribution(10, 15, 20).samplesVector(100)
```

On the other hand, if I remove the "new" keyword, then I get the following message:

```
No implicit arguments of type: TriangularDistribution.Impl3[Double, Double, Double, VR_]
```

How do I generate the same DenseVector using the same seed for Triangular distribution? Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand how you're getting that latter error, but the issue is that `samplesVector` is a method on Breeze distributions, while you have an Apache distribution. You can wrap TriangularDistribution by following what we did for e.g. [the F Distribution](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/blob/1e1eca52d4118fa2ca1c16d63f420cd261f71c40/math/src/main/scala/breeze/stats/distributions/FDistribution.scala)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, however I am not sure I understand. Triangular distribution is already wrapped and available in Breeze: https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/blob/1e1eca52d4118fa2ca1c16d63f420cd261f71c40/math/src/main/scala/breeze/stats/distributions/TriangularDistribution.scala
However, this does not answer how I can have something like `samplesVector`, through which we can generate a repeatable vector. Did you mean something else?